# how can I retrieve an USERID from a web site user,  when it adds a new FILE on SP?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, web-services

I'm building a WebServices  tha allows user from a social network to add a new FILE in a DoCLibrary. 
This WebServices' WSDl ,was built with no "USERID" field .
Every time that someone add a new file on sharepoint, it's created as "SHAREPOINT/SYSTEM" author.
So, every Domain user has his own account on sharepoint that is the same on the web site social network. 
 I need to knows how can I get the user instance that is logged on the WebSite , that is adding a new file on SP, to modify that "FILE AUTHOR"field  on sharepoint ?

Comment: Just to clarify what your asking... Once a user adds a new file, the web service should check if the user exists and if so add the user as the author, but if not, to create the user account on the domain, and then add the user as author?

Comment: no, the user already exists on the domain. Both SP userid and Social Network userid are gotten gotten by domain. But when call the web services method which adds a file, the wsdl doesn't have the user id field but only "fileName, fileID, contentID," When the file is created, it's created with Author property ="Sharpoint\system". That's because the web services method works with  "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a textbox set it to read only and in the default value settings feild under properties, you can add a function in this case *UserName()* which will pull from active directory.

I hope this is what you were looking for.